# Unable to register .net COM DLL

Tags: .net

I have registered a .net COM dll using the regasm tool and the registration was successful. It says 'Type registered successfully'. But when I open registry I cannot see my dll there. I searched using both ProgId & clsId but not there.

I registered another dll too in same way and it got registered successfully and I am able to access it from a VB6 dll.

What problem could it be. Something wrong with the dll? I set the project properties for both my dlls in same way and one seems to got registered successfully.

I am supposed to test the dll accessing from an existing vb6 tool and unable to start it.

Thanks

Nishitha

Comment: I take it the DLL is marked for COM interop in the project properties?

Comment: I have checked the option 'Make assembly COM visible' in the project's properties. I believe I don't have to check 'Register for COM interop' as we are doing the same using regasm

Comment: There are *four* versions of Regasm.exe, 32-bit vs 64-bit and v2 vs v4.  75% odds you'll use the wrong one.  100% when it turns into an SO question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `regasm.exe` with the `/regfile` option. This will create a reg file containing all entries that are going to be created when registering an assembly.

If the file does not contain any entries, your assembly does not export any COM types. Then you need to make sure that you either flag the *Make assembly COM visible* option in the project properties or use the `[ComVisible(true)]` attribute on the respective types.

If you are on a 64-bit system, make sure you are using the correct version of regasm as there are separate versions for 32-bit and 64-bit:

- `%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<framework version>\regasm.exe`
- `%SYSTEMROOT%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\<framework version>\regasm.exe`

Comment: Using /regfile I could see 4 entries in the reg file which are some enums. I could not see my COM visible class entry present in it. The other dll (which got registered fine and im able to access) has the details of my COM visible class in reg file. My assembly is COM visible and have set my class also with [ComVisibleAttribute(true)]

Answer (score 1):

I know it's six years late, but for anyone with this problem: You also need to make sure that the types you are trying to register are public. (It's easy to overlook, from my own experience.)